# why can't I render only freestyle stuff while using eevee?

Tags: compositing-nodes, eevee-render-engine, freestyle, render-passes

I'm working on a cartoon character using eevee and I want to add freestyle to it. in 2.79 I used to render freestyle lines in a separate layer and since I only used cycles, I could just hide the mesh in one layer like this:

[image]

After this I would have a freestyle layer that I could composite however I want.

The problem is that eevee for some reason doesn't have this View Layer>Filter tab.[image]

So the only way to make this work is going to cycles, render the freetyle layer, going back to eevee and rendering the surface layer, and this would be ok if I didn't want to render an animation.

I need to know some way to work around this and the reason why eevee doesn't have the "filter" tab in the View Layer.

Comment: Why does it get not OK only if you want to render an animation? What's different with rendering an animation with EEVEE and rendering an animation with Cycles and then compositing them from rendering stills and then compositing them?

Comment: I don't exactly know how to do it with an animation, and it would just be more simple to just have this option to disable surfaces in eevee